# Tkinter, have two separate boards that can be referenced

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

Probably the problem lies in the commented part.

I must have two tabs on the screen. These two chessboards must interact with each other: if I click on the white or black button of one chessboard, in the other chessboard the corresponding red button must become white or black respectively; instead if you click two red buttons you must have information on the "information content".

Se invece introduco il secondo tabellone, accadono i disastri. La prima scheda non subisce modifiche, le modifiche interessano solo la seconda scheda.

How can I have two separate boards but they can be referenced?

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import random

# random generator of visible part
visible = np.zeros((6,6))
count1 = 0
count2 = 0

for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        if count1 == 18:
            visible[i][j] = 1
            count2 = count2+1
        elif count2 == 18:
            visible[i][j] = 0
            count1 = count1+1
        elif np.random.uniform(0,1) <= 0.5 and count1 < 19:
            visible[i][j] = 0
            count1 = count1+1
        else:
            visible[i][j] = 1
            count2 = count2+1

print(visible)

# random generator of invisible part
img = np.zeros((6,6))
count1 = 0
count2 = 0

for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        if count1 == 28:
            img[i][j] = 1
            count2 = count2+1
        elif count2 == 8:
            img[i][j] = 0
            count1 = count1+1
        elif np.random.uniform(0,1) <= 0.75 and count1 < 31:
            img[i][j] = 0
            count1 = count1+1
        else:
            img[i][j] = 1
            count2 = count2+1

print(img)

click = 0
start = 0
finish = 0

class Layout(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, n=6):
        super().__init__()
        self.n = n
        self.leftframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.leftframe.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=10, padx=100)
        self.middleframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.middleframe.grid(row=0, column=6, rowspan=6)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=1000, height=500, )
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=6, rowspan=6)
        self.board = [[None for row in range(n)] for col in range(n)]

    def drawboard(self):
        for col in range(self.n):
            color = "#ff0000"
            for row in range(self.n):
                x1 = col * 60
                y1 = (5-row) * 60
                x2 = x1 + 60
                y2 = y1 + 60
                if(visible[5-row][col] == 0):
                    self.board[row][col] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=color, tags=f"tile{col+1}{row+1}")
                    self.canvas.tag_bind(f"tile{col+1}{row+1}","<Button-1>", lambda e, i=col, j=row: self.get_location(e,i,j))
                else:
                    if(img[5-row][col] == 0):
                        self.board[row][col] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1+5, y1+5, x2-5, y2-5, fill="white", tags=f"tile{col+1}{row+1}")
                        self.canvas.tag_bind(f"tile{col+1}{row+1}","<Button-1>", lambda e, i=col, j=row: self.get_info(e,i,j))
                    else:
                        self.board[row][col] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1+5, y1+5, x2-5, y2-5, fill="black", tags=f"tile{col+1}{row+1}")
                        self.canvas.tag_bind(f"tile{col+1}{row+1}","<Button-1>", lambda e, i=col, j=row: self.get_info(e,i,j))

    def get_info(self, event, i, j):
        x1 = i * 60
        y1 = (5-j) * 60
        x2 = x1 + 60
        y2 = y1 + 60
        global click
        #discover a box of other board
        if click == 6:
            if(img[5-j][i] == 0):
                self.board[i][j] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="white")
            else:
                self.board[i][j] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="black")
            click = 0
            print("click counter reset")

    def get_location(self, event, i, j):
        x1 = i * 60
        y1 = (5-j) * 60
        x2 = x1 + 60
        y2 = y1 + 60
        global click
        global start
        global finish
        if click < 6 and click%2 == 0:
            start = i
            finish = j
            click = click+1
        elif click < 6 and click%2 == 1:
            if img[i][j] != img[start][finish]:
                print("information difference")
            else:
                print("equality of information")
            click = click+1
        #print (i+1, j+1)
'''
    def drawboard2(self):
        for col in range(self.n):
            color = "#ff0000"
            for row in range(self.n):
                x1 = col * 60 + 600
                y1 = (5-row) * 60
                x2 = x1 + 60
                y2 = y1 + 60
                if(visible[5-row][col] == 1):
                    self.board[row][col] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=color, tags=f"tile{col+1}{row+1}")
                    self.canvas.tag_bind(f"tile{col+1}{row+1}","<Button-1>", lambda e, i=col, j=row: self.get_location2(e,i,j))
                else:
                    if(img[5-row][col] == 0):
                        self.board[row][col] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1+5, y1+5, x2-5, y2-5, fill="white", tags=f"tile{col+1}{row+1}")
                        self.canvas.tag_bind(f"tile{col+1}{row+1}","<Button-1>", lambda e, i=col, j=row: self.get_info2(e,i,j))
                    else:
                        self.board[row][col] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1+5, y1+5, x2-5, y2-5, fill="black", tags=f"tile{col+1}{row+1}")
                        self.canvas.tag_bind(f"tile{col+1}{row+1}","<Button-1>", lambda e, i=col, j=row: self.get_info2(e,i,j))

    def get_info2(self, event, i, j):
        x1 = i * 60 + 600
        y1 = (5-j) * 60
        x2 = x1 + 60
        y2 = y1 + 60
        global click
        #discover a box of other board
        if click == 6:
            if(img[5-j][i] == 0):
                self.board[i][j] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="white")
            else:
                self.board[i][j] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="black")
            click = 0
            print("click counter reset")

    def get_location2(self, event, i, j):
        x1 = i * 60 + 600
        y1 = (5-j) * 60
        x2 = x1 + 60
        y2 = y1 + 60
        global click
        global start
        global finish
        if click < 6 and click%2 == 0:
            start = i
            finish = j
            click = click+1
        elif click < 6 and click%2 == 1:
            if img[i][j] != img[start][finish]:
                print("information difference")
            else:
                print("equality of information")
            click = click+1
        #print (i+1, j+1)
'''

board = Layout()
board.drawboard()
#board.drawboard2()
board.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you name the second board exactly the same as the first one, the reference to the first widget will be lost and all changes only affect the second one. You can't even remove the first, anymore. You should give them individual variable names. You don't need two `.drawboard()` methods, you need only one of them but it should define two boards.

Comment: I don't want to steal too much time, but you could give me a small example (even independent of my code) @MartinWettstein

Answer (score 1):

What you'll need to do is to create the second board with different names and references. You only have one `self.board`. If you overwrite it when drawing the second board, you'll lose the information on the first board that was previously stored.

You'll need a second board list. The `.drawboard()` and `.get_location()` methods can be fashioned to handle both boards at once.

Just create the two simultaneously in the first go:

```
       ## Get a reference list for both boards.
       self.board1 = [[None for row in range(n)] for col in range(n)]
       self.board2 = [[None for row in range(n)] for col in range(n)]

    def drawboard(self):
        for col in range(self.n):
            color = "#ff0000"
            for row in range(self.n):
                x1 = col * 60
                y1 = (5-row) * 60
                x2 = x1 + 60
                y2 = y1 + 60
                if(visible[5-row][col] == 0):
                    ## Rectangle on board 1
                    self.board1[row][col] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=color, tags=f"tile1{col+1}{row+1}")
                    self.canvas.tag_bind(f"tile1{col+1}{row+1}","<Button-1>", lambda e, i=col, j=row, board=1: self.get_location(e,i,j,board))
                    
                    ## Rectangle on board 2
                    self.board2[row][col] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1+600, y1, x2+600, y2, fill=color, tags=f"tile2{col+1}{row+1}")
                    self.canvas.tag_bind(f"tile2{col+1}{row+1}","<Button-1>", lambda e, i=col, j=row, board=2: self.get_location(e,i,j,board))

...(and so on)
```

Wen you click on a tile, you will call the method `.get_location()` with three arguments. i,j, and board. Then, you can handle the request.

```
    def get_location(self, event, i, j, board):
        xshift = 0
        if board==2: xshift = 600
        x1 = i * 60 + xshift
        y1 = (5-j) * 60
        x2 = x1 + 60 + xshift
        y2 = y1 + 60

        ...
```

Additionally, I would replace the global variables within the class by class attributes. So, you don't have to define them as global, all the time. Just store the values in `self.click`, `self.start` and so on. So, you can see and change them in all methods.